# SSMS 2014 Table Designer - Data Type AutoComplete Not Working Properly

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, ssms-2014

I just noticed this odd bug and was wondering if anyone else has seen it and knows of a solution.

When using the table designer, if you tab into the data type field and start typing, the field will not clear entirely to allow you to enter the type you want. The first keypress selects a type from the list. All subsequent keypresses are prepended to that selected type.

For example, I wanted to change the type to "nvarchar". After typing the "n", the data type changed to "nchar(10)", which is normal behavior. However, the remaining keypresses did not clear the selection to allow for "nvarchar". Instead, the result was "varcharnchar(10)". The same behavior occurs if you clear the field entirely before typing.

It seems the only ways to get the correct value (that I've found) are to either type it out then go back and edit the value or select the desired type from the list and edit the size (if needed). Of course, I can avoid the designer and create my table with T-SQL directly, but I'm rather accustomed to the designer (and curious about the issue).

I've been running on Windows 10 with a new Dell Inspiron 15 7000 (with the high density display) for a couple of weeks, but haven't noticed the issue until today. Windows doesn't always play well with these displays yet, but SSMS seemed to be working fine until now.

Also, it appears that there were several system updates on May 26th, so I'm curious if anyone can say they've seen the issue after those updates as well. I couldn't identify one that was an obvious culprit and I was hoping I wouldn't need to uninstall/reinstall one at a time.

Thanks!

Comment: The best solution to this problem would be to stop using the table designer entirely. It is so easy to just code tables. It takes a little bit longer at first but once you learn the syntax it is SO much faster and eliminates this kind of stuff altogether.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really consider that a solution to what appears to be a bug. After 20+ years, I'm actually very familiar with the syntax. I honestly like the designer - especially if I'm making a few quick changes.

Comment: If it is truly a bug then you should post a connect item about it.

Comment: Is it truly a bug? Is it an issue with SSMS? Windows? Was it the result of a system update or my laptop's display drivers? There was only one other post on the MS forums about this issue and the recommendation was the same as yours. While I appreciate the professional opinion, I was hoping this forum would provide additional insight.

Comment: I can't speak to it truly being a bug. I don't use the table designer myself. I did try this out on a 2014 instance and did not experience the problems you are describing.

Comment: Thanks for checking.

Comment: @WonderGrub you found a solution for this ? it's so annoying

Comment: Hey @Kris - It's actually not doing it anymore. I literally just noticed it a few days ago day, but I haven't been creating or editing tables lately. I just looked at my update history and see a couple of Windows 10 updates on 6/15 - KB3149135 and KB3163018. Not sure if that's what did it, but I would say it's worth checking for updates. If it does, I would love to hear back.

Comment: @Kris - I don't know what's going on, but I had another update last night and now the issue is back. On 7/12, I received KB3172985 and KB3173428 - both updates for Win 10 Version 1511. There were also updates for Flash and Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool. It seems less likely that they would have affected it, but who knows.